# running idea in debugger with -P arguments

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to run debugger in Idea with -P arguments, but cannot find a way to do so.

I can run it on the command line e.g.

```
runLocal -PConfigPath=config.yml -PuseM
```

I have tried putting the -P variables into VM args, Program Args, and Environment args, but they all fail to pick up.

Comment: -DConfigPath maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to use -D and give the environment arguments, i just hadn't meat -P before.